# Openrefine not working as expected

Tags: openrefine

I'm very new to OpenRefine, so please bear with me if i have made a simple mistake.
I'm parsing a HTML website to gather some date.

Everything went fine with fetching the individual pages, but now the parsing of the HTML fails.
I'm creating a new column, based on the one holding all the page's HTML. I'm trying to get to the data in a specific DIV[20].

In the"create column based on this column" window it gives me a preview when using `value.parseHtml().select("DIV")[20]` , which results in exactly what i need... executing it gives me nothing but blank cells.
 it even tells me that it is "filling 0 rows with grel:value.parseHtml().select("DIV")[20]"

Any clue what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to finalize with .toString() to output the JSON.org object AS a string.

This is explained on our wiki here: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/StrippingHTML#extract-html-attributes-text-links-with-integrated-grel-commands

I also updated the select() function with that example: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Other-Functions#selectelement-e-string-s